# Move image up on mouse over

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to move my image up by 10px on mouse-over but for some reason that doesn't work. 
Here is what I have tried:

http://jsfiddle.net/w3qqv4vh/

CSS:

```
.image {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 238px;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  overflow: hidden;

.image:hover {
  margin-bottom: 10px;    
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  -moz-transition: margin-left .5s; /* Firefox 4 */
  -webkit-transition: margin-left .5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transition: margin-left .5s; /* Opera */
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/w3qqv4vh/2/

Comment: for your main class .image, change it to display: in-line block instead, and position: relative. After that when you use your hover event do margin-top: -10px;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some changes that you need to do on the css.

**CSS**

```
.image {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
    top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 238px;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  }

.image:hover {
  margin-top: -10px;    
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  -moz-transition: margin-left .5s; /* Firefox 4 */
  -webkit-transition: margin-left .5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transition: margin-left .5s; /* Opera */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w3qqv4vh/1/

Answer (score 0):

transition is applied on `.image` not `.image:hover` and just use `transform`

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 200;
  line-height: 1.38;
  color: #000000;
}


.image {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 238px;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transform:translateY(0);
  transition: transform .5s ease;
} 
.image:hover {
  -webkit-transform:translateY(-10px);  
}
```

```html
  <img class="image" alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-284-239-1.jpg">
```

You can use padding too

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 200;
  line-height: 1.38;
  color: #000000;
}


.image {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 238px;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: padding-bottom .5s ease;
}
  
.image:hover {
  padding-bottom: 10px;    
  
}
```

```html
  <img class="image" alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-284-239-1.jpg">
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kougiland/w3qqv4vh/3/)